# Rails 4 - disable_with: not replacing button text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The disable button part works, but the text is not being replaced?

```
<%= form_for [@section, @deficiency] do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :quality_checklist_id, value: @quality_check_list.id if @quality_check_list %>
<%= f.hidden_field :unit_id, value: @unit.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :trade_id, value: @section.trade_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :task_id, value: @section.task_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :section_id, value: @section.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :deficiency_category_id, value: params[:sub] %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10, style: 'width:100%' %>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= f.file_field :image %><br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="center">
    <%= f.button "Create", class: "btn btn-primary", data: {disable_with: "Stand by ..."} %>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="center">
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', inspect_unit_path(@unit), class: 'btn', data: { confirm: 'CANCEL?' } %>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that replace text works in Chrome but not Safari.

Comment: Do you have `jquery-rails` gem installed?

Comment: Yes, I just discovered the replace text works in Chrome but not Safari ...